# Fix console output in Vistual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, cmd, console

in the normal console log output Output normal does not move anywhere, but when I try to run it through vs code, then there all shifts, new text printed over the old, etc., how can you fix it?

[Normal Console Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tjy0C.jpg)

[Vs Code Console Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ee7g6.jpg)

I added in settings this parameters, but its not helped:

```
"terminal.integrated.scrollback": 10000,
"terminal.integrated.fontFamily": "Consolas"
```

Comment: What shell is being used in your VS Code integrate terminal?

Comment: @user Command Promt